# NodeJs,ExpressJS Running functions in background

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, background-process

im asking this question because i dont know what to look for right now and my googling wasnt great so far.

I am making nodejs,express,sql app that scrape website. It takes 30 to 120 seconds to scrape whole category. How to make that function run in the background without blocking website. Frontend template engine is eJS. If its not possible to do with eJS which framework,library should i use then? I imagine it work like that

1. User go to /scrape
2. Choose category and send to server by clicking button
3. Some container on /scrape gets greyed out with circle rotating or
   other % or smth
4. User can freely leave /scrape and click around webiste or just stay
   on /scrape waiting for result
5. When user cames back to /scrape the results are there or when he
   stayed results shows up with or without reloading the page

Getting full respond to these questions will be very helpfull. But just keywords for me to look up also are very helpfull

Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 1):

For your case here you could use redis, or just store the data you scrape on an data structrue that you like (in my opinion, because of the category, hashmaps (js objects) are the best here) directly in nodejs. The process would then look like this:

1. User goes to /scrape and selects a category
2. Backend checks if that category was already scraped (e.g. checks for the data in the hashmap with the category name as key)
3. If the data exists (just check if the key is defined), then send the data to the user, else (if the data isn't stored, e.g. key == undefined), send the user a message that the data is beign scraped and just run the scrape funtion in the backround. The scrape function than scrapes the data, and if it is done, it pushes the data with the category key to the hashmap. To avoid the same categorys beign scraped at the same time, you could add a "pending" property to the hashmap. So if the user accesses the /scrape route, you check in the hashmap if the category key exsists, if yes and pending is false, send data, if yes and pending is true, send wait alert, if the key doesn't exists, start the scrape function and send a wait alter.

Additionally, to make the whole thing "live", you could use socket.io (https://socket.io/) to implement websockets. You could then send the scraped data to the user without the user having to reload the page to check if the scrape process is done.

I made a little exmaple, that doesn't implement scraping, but should make the whole logic here a little bit easier to understand. I also added some explenation to the code in form of comments.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express()

// the data hashmap
const data = {};

// scrape function
const scrape = async (id) => {
  // set pending to true to prevent multiple scraped on same category
  data[id] = { pending: true, data: {} }
  // this would be your scrape functio, I used a promise here that
  // resolves after 5 seconds with an random number just for
  // simplicity
  const a = await new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => { res(Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)) }, 5000)
  })

  // if the data was scraped, set pending to false and add the data
  data[id].pending = false;
  data[id].data = { id: a }
}

// "scrape" route
app.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params; // if would represent category

  // check if id (category) is not in hashmap, if not, then
  // start the scrape process and send a wait alert
  if (data[id] == undefined) {
    scrape(id);
    res.send("scraping...")

  // if the data is already beign scraped, send a wait alert
  // the pending property prvents that multiple people trigger
  // the scrape of the same category
  } else if (data[id].pending == true) {
    res.send("still scraping...")

  // lastly, if the data is defined, and is not pending, then
  // you could just send it
  } else {
    res.send(data[id].data)
  }
})


// to test this, go to the root with any id, could be string, number,
// whatever (e.g. /1337 or /helloworld), wait for 5 seceonds (or
// leave and come back after 5 seconds), refresh the page and you can
// see the random number. If you now go to an other route (e.g /test)
// and go back to the last one, you still can see the data, if you again
// wait for 5 seconds and then go back to /test, you can see the data.
// You can also open multiple tabs at the same time, which means the
// scraping is asynchronous, so you don't have to wait for the
// one category to be scraped to scrape the next 

app.listen(5000)
```